# Where else should we advertise for the Solana StackExchange?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

We currently have advertising in Anchor + Solana Tech Discords, Twitter, and Telegram. Where else can we go to reach more Solana Developers about the StackExchange?

Comment: The current area51 stats have visits per day at only 200, which is pretty low. Does google index the answers yet?

Comment: @HenryE My understanding is that google doesn't index answers until we hit public beta

Answer (score 6):

The Solana Github project readme files would be an easy win. Beyond that, the Solana documentation site as well as the cookbook.